# error WTRN0006W in webSphere - Transaction has timed out after 120 seconds - in JBoss and Tomcat everything is OK

Tags: oracle, view, timeout, websphere

I have a big riddle.
Code, which I modified was not clean - sql was generated as string (over 100 lines of sql code) etc ...
I moved a big sql query to oracle view and in Java code I make fast select on view.
It working good on JBoss and Tomcat.
On the other hand in WebSphere (used by client) I have an error after select in view.

```
[5/22/15 12:20:24:043 CEST] 00000022 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0006W: Transaction 0000014D7B2185A800000002000001B660A70E3F35C49F79E7F2FBE65BD336F30DB8D5FC0000014D7B2185A800000002000001B660A70E3F35C49F79E7F2FBE65BD336F30DB8D5FC00000001 has timed out after 120 seconds.
[5/22/15 12:21:14:042 CEST] 00000056 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[action]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:553)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:994)
    at pl.com.max.primer.action.ajax.BaseAjaxAction.execute(BaseAjaxAction.java:78)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
    at pl.com.max.primer.plugin.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:135)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:591)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3453)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1466)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
```

Comment: Do you have any other exceptions in the log? Add relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your query is executing longer than 120 seconds. Maybe max transaction timeouts in JBoss or Tomcat are higher. You have to verify why this query is taking so long and try to make it faster. If it wont be possible you can extend transaction timeout via admin console.

Click `Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name.` Then click  `Container Services > Transaction Service`. And set  `Maximum transaction timeout`.

See here for more details: [Configuring transaction properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tjta_settlog.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-9-6-2-0&lang=en)

Comment: It must be an error WebSphere <==> Oracle db, becouse I have got feedback info from admin, that in WebSphere run other applications, which uses views. What oracle have any variable or setup, which block use view? ;o (In JBoss <==> oracle  everything is good)